# Rails 3: Lazy loading versus eager loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails 3, are these the same, or different? How do they differ?

```
o = Appointment.find(297)
o.service


o = Appointment.includes(:service).find(297)
o.service
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure, but it looks like you have `belongs_to :serivce` in the `Appointment` class and `has_many :appointments` the `Service` class. Correct?

In that case there won't be any difference between your 2 examples. Rails will execute 2 queries in both cases:

```
Appointment Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "appointments".* FROM "appointments" WHERE ("appointments"."id" = 1) LIMIT 1
Service Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "services".* FROM "services" WHERE ("services"."id" = 1) LIMIT 1
```

If, on the other hand, you were calling:

```
s = Service.find(123)
```

and then do something like:

```
s.appointments.find(1)
s.appointments.find(2)
```

etc. in many places in the code, then there would be as many queries to the database as the number of these calls (Rails 3 is pretty smart here, so if you executed `s.appointments.each` it would actually fetch all the appointments in 1 query).

In that case it'd be better to call:

```
s = Service.include(:appointments).find(123)
```

because then Rails will execute only 2 queries: one to fetch the `Service` and one to fetch all the appointments:

```
Service Load ( 0.0ms )  SELECT "services".* FROM "services" WHERE ("services"."i
d" = 123) LIMIT 1
Appointment Load ( 0.0ms )  SELECT "appointments".* FROM "appointments" WHERE ("
appointments".service_id = 123)
```