# eager loading and lazy loading in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am confused about eager loading and lazy loading, is there any difference in the performance of rails queries?

Is there any way to implement both ways?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

[**Eager Loading**](http://railscasts.com/episodes/22-eager-loading)

One way to improve performance is to cut down on the number of SQL queries. You can do this through eager loading.

```
User.find(:all, :include => :friends)
```

Here you are firing only two queries :

1) One for all users.

2) One for all friends of users .

[**Lazy Loading**](http://weblogs.asp.net/fbouma/archive/2007/04/16/more-on-lazy-loading-vs-pre-loading-in-o-r-mapping-scenarios.aspx) :

When you have an object associated with many objects like a User has many Friends and you want to display a list as in Orkut you fire as many queries as there are friends, plus one for the object itself.

```
users = User.find(:all)
```

Then query for each user friend , like :

```
users.each do |user|
  friend = Friend.find_by_user_id(user.id)
end
```

Here

1) One query for all users.

2) N query for N no. of users friends .

Take a look on : [Rails 3: Lazy loading versus eager loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975149/rails-3-lazy-loading-versus-eager-loading)

Hope that will help you to understand this .

Comment: Check this as well : http://www.spritle.com/blogs/2011/03/17/eager-loading-and-lazy-loading-in-rails-activerecord/

Comment: Lazy loading is not the same as not using eager loading. 

`"Lazy loading is a design pattern commonly used in computer programming to defer initialization of an object until the point at which it is needed. It can contribute to efficiency in the program's operation if properly and appropriately used." -Wikipedia`

Basically if your page has a bunch of images that a user doesn't see until he scrolls, you can wait until he scrolls down and will see the image to load it. That is lazy loading.

Comment: @aaron-coding The original author's question was specifically with regard to Rails' [ActiveRecord's] lazy/eager loading. In that context it is not just about deferred initialization - lazy loading in Rails can entail significantly more database queries, which come with a material performance cost. In this regard they may not contribute to efficiency, though in other circumstances they may - for instance, in cases in which memory, rather than database load, is the primary constraint.

Answer (score 22):

**Eager loading**

Pro: is that everything's ready to go.

Con: you are using up space/memory.

**Lazy Loading**

An anecdote might help you remember:

```
A young naval cadet asked Lord Nelson why he wasn't preparing his ships:
```

> "I won't load my guns early.......I'll load just 1 microsecond before
> I need to fire it." he said. "I'm being lazy. I prefer doing it at the
> last minute, just like with my university assignments etc."

Pro of lazy loading: you don't hit the database until you need to.

Con: You'll be hitting the database N + 1 times.....unless you select exactly the column you want and you alias it. e.g.

```
@products = Product.order("categories.name").joins(:category)
```

**Hitting the Database only once with a lazy loading policy:**

The above query hits the database N + 1 times when you call `product.category.name` in the view template - where product is a single object within the `@products` relation. But if you alias it, you can get everything done with just one query:

```
@products = Product.order("categories.name").joins(:category).select("products.*, categories.name as category_name")
```

And use it like this: product.category_name