# Ruby on Rails where()

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm doing my ruby project but i got a problem.
I have a problem on where in ruby like below.

```
@talk = Talk.where(params[:ask])
```

I get

```
"#<Talk::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f811404dae8>"
```

this from `@talk`.
I'm finding the value of the answer in my db with ask.
How can I print the value of the talk with `where()`?

Comment: What is in `params[:ask]`? and what are the columns in the database you're trying to search on?

Where will return a collection.  If you only want the first record matching the query then add `.first` on the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have distinct ask values in your talk objects then you can do

```
@talk = Talk.find_by(ask: params[:ask])
```

which will return a single talk object. If no such ask value can be found nil is returned.

Answer (score 1):

The objects are only retrieved when special methods like first, each etc are called. This is called lazy loading.

`@talk = Talk.where(params[:ask])`

`@talk = Talk.where(params[:ask]).first`

This way you will get the first entry which will be returned by your where, you can read some more about the lazy loading vs eager loading on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10084355/eager-loading-and-lazy-loading-in-rails) thread

Answer (score 1):

`where()` will return a collection object. You are missing a column name with it.

If you want to access one object from the collection, use

```
@talk = Talk.where(column_name: params[:ask]).first #Or Talk.where(column_name: params[:ask]).last depending on the requirement
```

If you want to access all objects, you will have to loop through every object returned,

```
@talks = Talk.where(column_name: params[:ask])

-unless @talk.nil?
  @talks.each do |talk|
    = talk.column_name
```